# How to auto-format the QLabel text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlabel

I would like the text to auto-fit inside of the label. 
As the width of the QLabel gets more narrow the text formats to occupy multiple lines. Essentially I am looking for a way to format it the same way a html text is formatted when we resize the web browser window.

```
label=QtGui.QLabel()  

text = "Somewhere over the rainbow Way up high And the dreams that you dreamed of Once in a lullaby"    

label.setText(text)
label.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried label.setWordWrap(True)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using `QLabel`'s `resizeEvent()` to get a real-time label's width value which is used to format the label's monofont text on a fly:

[image]

```
text = "Somewhere over the rainbow Way up high And the dreams that you dreamed of Once in a lullaby..."    

class Label(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)  

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.formatText()
        event.accept()

    def formatText(self):
        width = self.width()
        text = self.text()
        new = ''
        for word in text.split():
            if len(new.split('\n')[-1])<width*0.1:
                new = new + ' ' + word
            else:
                new = new + '\n' + ' ' + word
        self.setText(new)

myLabel = Label()
myLabel.setText(text)
myLabel.resize(300, 50)
font = QtGui.QFont("Courier New", 10)
font.setStyleHint(QtGui.QFont.TypeWriter)
myLabel.setFont(font)
myLabel.formatText()
myLabel.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong with _Frank Osterfeld_ suggestion ? I'm pretty sure wordWrap property will do that for you.

Comment: Fran's suggestions is great! I have missed his comment. I wish I would see it sooner! Thanks!